# Getting duplicate records in destination table while inserting and updating same record

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a source table (tSrc) on which we have insert and update after trigger is set. This trigger inserts and updates records in intermediate table (tIntSrc) with one flag column as I for insert and U for update. So if I inserted one row in tSrc table then tIntSrc will have one record with flag column as 'I' and if update it in tSrc then will have another record with flag column 'U'. So I have 2 identical records with flag column value as 'I' and 'U'.

I have written one stored procedure which picks up first records from tIntSrc table with flag status 'I' in cursor and inserts in destination table (tDest) and then once insertion completes then it picks up records from tIntSrc table with flag status 'U' in a different cursor. This will update the record in tDest table that we have inserted and once this insertion and upadtion of records completed I am updating the flag column to 'C' i.e. complete so that it will never come for next fetch.

But my problem is some how there will be two records in tDest table instead of just one.
I m not able to understand how to resolve this. please help

Comment: Without any code, this is a guess based on your description - but an UPDATE in SQL equals a DELETE and INSERT, so the UPDATE might also trigger your INSERT logic due to this?

Comment: You will need to post the details of the procedure and tables for us to properly help you.